# How to assign a method to a RadioButton?

Tags: android

I have five `RadioButton` widgets in `Activity x`,  and five methods in `Activity y`.  I want to assign a particular method to each `RadioButton` so when the user select a button in `Activity x` a method in `Activity y` is implemented

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I would suggest some further reading to ensure you fully understand the output of this code.

1. [Android - RadioGroup control](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_radiogroup_control.htm)
2. [Radio Group - Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html)
3. [Radio Button - Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html)

you'll need to create the RadioGroup and RadioButton widgets inside your layout file.

```
<RadioGroup
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="90dp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
      android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
      android:weightSum="1"
      android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3">

      <RadioButton
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="55dp"
         android:text="Male"
         android:id="@+id/radioButton"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:checked="false"
         android:textSize="25dp" />

      <RadioButton
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Female"
         android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:checked="false"
         android:textSize="25dp"
         android:layout_weight="0.13" />
   </RadioGroup>

<Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="New Button"
      android:id="@+id/button"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Make note of the `android:checked` attribute, if set to true, that `RadioButton` will be checked by default and vise versa.

You'll then need to initialize the `RadioGroup` inside your activity then see which of them is checked.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   private RadioGroup radioSexGroup;
   private RadioButton radioSexButton;
   private Button btnDisplay;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      radioSexGroup=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

      btnDisplay=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

      btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            int selectedId=radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            radioSexButton=(RadioButton)findViewById(selectedId);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,radioSexButton.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

**Note**: the above code has total credit to TutorialsPoint, as shown in the 1st link provided above.

Now, if you want to check which button has been selected and perform some logic if it is, you can then use a `switch` statement with the `selectedId` you acquired from the `RadioGroup` using the syntax `int selectedid = radioSexGroup.getSelectedButtonId();`

So to see where the logic goes, the new snippet will look something like this:

```
        int selectedId=radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioSexButton=(RadioButton)findViewById(selectedId);
          switch(selectedId) {
                case R.id.radioButton: 
                       //perform logic is first button selected
                        break;

                case R.id.radiobutton2: 
                       //perform logic is second button selected
                        break;
          }
```

Hope this helps your understanding of `RadioGroup` and `RadioButton` objects.

You can also directly apply a listener to the `RadioGroup` to get the `checkedid` of the `RadioButton` that is selected without a button click like shown above.

```
radioSexGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) 
        {
            switch (checkedId) {
               case R.id.radiobutton:
                    //method for first radio button goes here
                    break;
               case R.id.radiobutton2:
                    //method for second radio button goes here
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```